# How to add a color to the header of a Telerik groupbox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight, telerik

How can I add a color to the header of a telerik groupbox?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <telerik:GroupBox Header="Demo">
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some built-in themes that you can apply directly to your GroupBox control. They provide some basic styling options and you may find the one that suits your need the most.

Built-in Themes: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/panels-and-labels/groupbox/themes

But, in case you really don't want to use the built-in themes and only wish to customize the UI, then you should be looking at Telerik Presentation Framework (TPF) and design and implement your own GroupBox control.

Change the GroupBox header color

```
((FillPrimitive)this.radGroupBox1.GroupBoxElement.Children[1].Children[0]).BackColor = Color.Red;
((FillPrimitive)this.radGroupBox1.GroupBoxElement.Children[1].Children[0]).BackColor2 = Color.Yellow;
((FillPrimitive)this.radGroupBox1.GroupBoxElement.Children[1].Children[0]).GradientStyle = Telerik.WinControls.Gradien
```

More details on TPF here:
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/panels-and-labels/groupbox/advanced/tpf-structure

Comment: FillPrimitive is for WinForms. I use WPF or Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

As WoodKiddy mentioned earlier it would be advisable to use the c# version - setting the color programmatically.
  It would seem that the telerik team themselves are suggesting the same here:

[This question seems similiar to yours](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=telerik%20groupbox%20headerstyle)

I'm not really used to the xaml structure and ***again the dev team*** suggests using the c# approach. But this might do the work with some luck:

```
<Style x:Key="MyGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
 <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
   <Setter.Value>
     <DataTemplate>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"/>
     </DataTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I can use C# in code behind. But I doubt it only supports WinForms. I use WPF or Silverlight. 

 

There are some built-in themes that you can apply directly to your GroupBox control. They provide some basic styling options and you may find the one that suits your need the most.

Built-in Themes is for WinForms.